# htaccess 301 redirect entire directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

After migrating ta large static site to wordpress (as well as a reconstruction), I have a permalink structure that differs from the original directory structure, yet the new post slugs are the same as the original filenames. It's also worth mentioning that the permalink structure mimics the file extension of the old file path.

For example:

what was once (static directory)

```
www.example.com/old/path/file.htm
```

is now (wordpress permalink structure)

```
www.example.com/new/path/file.htm (note: permalink structure mimics the .htm extension)
```

**My question**: Is there a simple htaccess rewrite rule that can redirect visitors from /path/to/file/(file.htm) to /new/path/to/(file.htm), without having to create a redirect for each file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using mod_alias is even easier:

```
Redirect 301 /old /new
```

But if you have rewrite rules in your htaccess file already, then you need to stick with using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^old/(.*)$ /new/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks, Jon, for the succinct response. Much appreciated!

Comment: One related question. If i have say, 20 or so of these rules, will I take a hit on performance?

Comment: @PeteSorensen it depends on how much traffic you get, but I've never noticed any issues with medium/low traffic sites. I've noticed running a PHP script is a bigger hit than 5000 rules.